# Is it Bad Practice to Implement a Single Page Application in this Fashion?

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

Okay,

So I have created this web application and it is designed to be a single page application.  There is a menu that just loads one of a variety of user controls (designed as forms) in a single update panel (clear controls, load new one, etc). The user does what ever inputs, clicks save, delete, etc.  Within these user controls, there are several databound and intradependant controls, which is the main reason I am loading them into an update panel.

Now, I have had this issue where when the user selects a new menu, and then goes to change the value of a databound control, the control loses its value on only the first postback.  I'm quite sure this is due to the clearing of the container that the usercontrol resides in, as I have tried clearing and loading a regular panel, and I would have the exact same issue.  As using (!IsPostBack) does not work in my case, i just created a boolean session variable to perform the same logic between the page and the usercontrol, in terms of databinding. To further test my issue, I changed the application to a multipage app, and the problem disappeared; values are retained on postback.

So, to get to my original point, as I see functionality in using mulitples pages; i figured that within the single page version, if I just added 'Server.Transfer(thedefaultpage.aspx)' to the code, I would retain the functionality I gained from the multipage approach, while keeping the user on the same page. It works great.  No loss of data, it works just as it should.  Is this in poor taste? All user functions and duties are always carried out on a single page, and navigation does nothing for them.

I am just worried that essentially refreshing the page is just bad practice or hacky, but it works for the purpose of the application, as well as save having to create 2-3 dozen pages when it may not be necessary.  I've read a few threads where someone would do this just to clear results, or something minor, but that is all.

If this is poor practice (or even if it is not), would perhaps anyone have a solution to the first time postback value loss? I have enableviewstate=true and viewstatemode=enabled on the master, page, usercontrol, and child controls that are databound.  Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 0):

This practice will lead to lot of problems in future. i wouldn't do like this

Answer (score 0):

So, in the event anyone comes across this same issue and is without a legitimate workaround, I "came up" with one the other day when I came back to solving this issue.

The first postback issue seems to stem from the clearing and repopulation of a container control (placeholder, panel, updatepanel, etc.).  As I had the user click on a menu item that would then clear and load usercontrols into the container, the usercontrol being referenced on postback differed from the new one being loaded. Bear with me on how I will attempt to describe the situation...

The last loaded usercontrol is referenced on the initial menu click, before the menu click event fires and then, the container is cleared and the new usercontrol is loaded from the menu click event.  This does not happen when there are no controls loaded in the container (initial startup). As the usercontrols are added dynamically, I have a method that reloads the currently loaded usercontrol, it is placed in Page_Init. This event, along with PreInit, _Load, all fire before control events, and was the cause of my problem.  The fix is, as will be obvious with more experience, is to add an if statement to both the usercontrol load method and Page_Init (or wherever you have the load method) that determines what is causing the postback.  As, I only want the user to click on menu items to move within the numerous tasks, I just made sure that if the menu item click is causing the postback, then, do not run the load method in Init, but, anything else that causes postback (for me, only within the user control), the load method within Init will only fire then.

Additionally, the if statement is necessary within the load method, to make sure all of controls within the newly added usercontrols contain default/empty values, essentially whatever defaults you want the user to see when the control is first displayed, in my case I had:

```
if (Page.Request.Params["_EVENTTARGET"].Contains("Menu1") == true) 
{ 
uc.Clear(null, null);
uc.SetBoundControls();
}
```

)

Hopefully this helps someone else, or sparks a thought towards a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is bad practice. WebForms have state problems that get steadily worse with increasing UI complexity.

I persist SPA UI state with a single class that is serialized to XML and saved to a database as plain text. I use a GUID in the URL as a session key (but you can have a user id, or the ASP.NET session ID, or whatever)  to retrieve this state information on every request, which eliminates any problems managing state or losing data when the user refreshes the page.

Doing this has the added benefit of allowing you to cover the logical UI with unit tests without getting tangled up in the web layer details - good for complex workflows.

If you try this, though, I would suggest that you consider moving to MVC and use plain old Post-and-Redirect; add hash tags to the redirect responses when you want to allow the back button.